# Keep until last occurrence of value per group

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a simplified example of my pandas dataframe:

```
     User  Binary
0   UserA       0
1   UserA       0
2   UserA       0
3   UserA       1
4   UserA       0
5   UserA       1
6   UserA       0
7   UserA       0
8   UserB       0
9   UserB       0
10  UserB       0
11  UserB       0
12  UserB       0
13  UserB       1
14  UserB       1
15  UserB       0
16  UserC       0
17  UserC       0
```

For each User, I would like to remove all rows after the first occurrence of Binary=1. Note, there will be some Users that have no cases of Binary=1, e.g. UserC in this example.

Output would look like below:

```
     User  Binary
0   UserA       0
1   UserA       0
2   UserA       0
3   UserA       1
8   UserB       0
9   UserB       0
10  UserB       0
11  UserB       0
12  UserB       0
13  UserB       1
16  UserC       0
17  UserC       0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach using `groupby` and transforming with a custom function:

```
# check which Binary values are 1 and group the series by User
g = df.Binary.eq(1).groupby(df.User)
# transform to either idxmax or the last index depending
# on whether there are any Trues or not
m = g.transform(lambda x: x.idxmax() if x.any() else x.index[-1])
# index the dataframe where the index is smaler or eq m
out = df[df.index <= m]
```

---

```
print(out)

     User  Binary
0   UserA       0
1   UserA       0
2   UserA       0
3   UserA       1
8   UserB       0
9   UserB       0
10  UserB       0
11  UserB       0
12  UserB       0
13  UserB       1
16  UserC       0
17  UserC       0
```

Answer (score 1):

Idea is test maximal value of consecutive values in swapped order by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), what working also if only `0` or only `1` groups values correctly:

```
def f(x):
    s = x.cumsum()
    return s.eq(s.max())
df = df[df.iloc[::-1].groupby('User')['Binary'].transform(f).sort_index()]
print (df)
     User  Binary
0   UserA       0
1   UserA       0
2   UserA       0
3   UserA       1
8   UserB       0
9   UserB       0
10  UserB       0
11  UserB       0
12  UserB       0
13  UserB       1
16  UserC       0
17  UserC       0
```